# CCS3 animation working on chrome but not in android html5 app

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I made a loader like facebook loader with css3 :

```
span.myLoader {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
span.loaderBars:before, 
span.loaderBars span, 
span.loaderBars:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 10px; height: 30px;
    background-color: #000000;
    animation: growLoader 1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: growLoader 1s linear infinite;
}
span.loaderBars:before {
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}
span.loaderBars span {
    left: 30px;
    animation-delay: -.33s;
    -webkit-animation-delay:  -.33s;
}
span.loaderBars:after {
    left: 15px;
    animation-delay: -.66s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -.66s;
}
@keyframes growLoader {
    0% {transform: scaleY(0); -webkit-transform: scaleY(0); opacity: 0;}
    50% {transform: scaleY(1); -webkit-transform: scaleY(1); opacity: 1;}
    100% {transform: scaleY(0); -webkit-transform: scaleY(0); opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes growLoader {
    0% {transform: scaleY(0); -webkit-transform: scaleY(0); opacity: 0;}
    50% {transform: scaleY(1); -webkit-transform: scaleY(1); opacity: 1;}
    100% {transform: scaleY(0); -webkit-transform: scaleY(0); opacity: 0;}
}
```

And html :

```
    <p><span class="myLoader loaderBars"><span></span></span></p>
```

it's work good on chrome but not in my android cordova app, what's wrong/missing ? I see only two bars and it's not animated...

Comment: SEE fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Kj9fn/ on android, red bar is hidden. the two others are not animated